# Every predicate I add in my JPA query is nested in parentheses "()"

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, openjpa

Today I was building an application for work and I noticed that all my predicates that I have in a JPA query gets nested in parentheses "()".

So this JPA query `select t from TestEntity t where t.field1 = :field1 AND t.field1 = :field1 AND t.field1 = :field1 AND t.field1 = :field1` gets translated to this `SELECT ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4 FROM TESTENTITY WHERE ((((FIELD1 = ?) AND (FIELD1 = ?)) AND (FIELD1 = ?)) AND (FIELD1 = ?))`.

I'm not sure why this happens and I thought this is not how it should work. Can someone help me with this?

I created a test project on my bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/brimirnl/example-jpa/src/master/
If you need more information let me know :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, but what is what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse?  Eclipse has some formatting options probably set in preferences that automatically surround your code with parentheses when it is formatted or saved.  Obviously someone wants it to be readable.  The parentheses just make it clearer to read.